# Why I keep getting invalid R-squared

Tags: r

I tried to use the formula of calculating R-squared, but both of them give me invalid R-squared, either negative or larger than 1.

I'm trying to use R-squared to evaluate my model fit. Thus calculating from the predicted value and actual value.

This is my actual data:

```
lasso_pred <- c(13.61946, 13.91595, 13.55052, 13.68006, 13.85825, 13.61735, 13.51712, 13.49727, 13.53181, 13.02560, 13.68658, 13.75073, 13.81856, 13.37798, 13.82558, 13.86672, 13.30965, 13.85373, 13.89834, 13.61562, 13.86353, 13.99774, 13.64185, 13.85063, 13.89282, 13.95036)

actual <- c(13.88986, 14.01917, 14.08782, 13.79533, 14.21647 ,14.18666, 13.84793, 14.02716 ,13.72207, 13.31198 ,13.99843,13.68277 ,13.81584, 13.81574, 14.24260 ,13.75368 ,13.71866 ,13.69617, 14.10187, 13.48185, 14.19855, 13.32519,13.61845, 13.81680, 13.94318, 14.09442)
```

```
   SSE <- sum((lasso_pred - actual)^2) #sum of squares residual
   SST <- sum((actual - mean(actual))^2)  #total sum of squares

   r2 <- 1-SSE/SST
```

```
   SSR <- sum((lasso_pred- mean(actual))^2)  #sum of squares regression
   SST <- sum((actual - mean(actual))^2)  #total sum of squares

   r2 <- SSR/SST
```

The calculated R-squared is not in the range of 0 and 1.

Comment: I think R^2 can be negative if your prediction is worse than the always predicting the mean. So, it is not necessarily invalid.

Comment: Your lasso_predict is worse than the mean. That is why your SSE > SST

Comment: @JonSpring She meant SSR as in Sum of Squared Errors due to regression not residuals.

Answer (score 1):

R^2 in general is not negative but in can be yet times when the predicted values are worse than a simple mean. Read this for [more](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative)